# Visual Studio - Some breakpoints not breaking

Tags: visual-studio-2010, breakpoints, windows-7-x64

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2010 with 9 projects which is under source control with Source Safe. I just recently swiped my hard-drive and upgraded to Win7 x64 from WinXP x86 (long overdue!). When I checked the solution out to the "new" machine, some parts are not working correctly now, so I'm trying to debug it.

Perhaps worth noting is that I was working in VS2008 before. When I upgraded, I first opened the project in VS2008 to make sure it worked and I noticed there were problems that I needed to debug. I set some breakpoints and a couple worked and a couple didn't. I couldn't immediately figure out why some weren't breaking, so I decided to go ahead and upgrade the project to VS2010 hoping it would work itself out. It didn't.

The main project calls a public sub in a public module in a project that is a library referenced by every other project. I have a breakpoint on the main form Form_Load which breaks successfully as soon as the code begins running. The Form_Load calls the aforementioned public sub which also has a breakpoint. But that breakpoint DOES NOT break. In other words, the debugger will stop on the call `ProjectStartupActions()` but will not stop on the definition `Public Sub ProjectStartupActions()` or any line in it.

If I "Go To Definition" on the sub call in Form_Load, it jumps to the correct place where I have the breakpoint, so I'm certain I've placed the breakpoint correctly.

My Project >> Debug >> Configuration is set to "Active (Debug)" and Platform is "Active (Any CPU)" for all projects. To further confirm that it should be running in Debug rather than Release, if I open an explorer window to the "Debug" folder for the library project and clean the project, the folder empties out. When I rebuild or run the files are all replaced.

Thanks for any help.

Oh yeah, also I made a change to the code of `Public Sub ProjectStartupActions()`. I added `MsgBox("Hello")` to the first line in the sub, but it never pops up.

Comment: Look in the Output window for a 'first chance exception' message.  Set the platform target to x86 to debug it.

Comment: I opened the output window, cleaned the project, then did a rebuild and a run. There were no "first chance exception" listed. Also, can you clarify why I need to target x86 specifically to debug? I will try your suggestion, but I have no problem stopping on a breakpoint in the main project with the current setting.

Comment: I set the Platform to x86 and it stopped on the breakpoint. It also popped the msgbox up. :) Awesome. Why does this not work for "Any CPU"? Also, I a newb on SO, how do I mark your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Set the target to x86 to debug it. –
>   Hans Passant

This worked! Thanks!! I used the Configuration Manager to change the target for the entire solution to x86.

But why did it work? Why did the "Any CPU" option break on the main project but not the library?

Comment: I too am curious as to why this works, and what the heck happened to this project to necessitate this...

Answer (score 0):

> Oh yeah, also I made a change to the code of `Public Sub ProjectStartupActions()`. I added `MsgBox("Hello")` to the first line in the sub, but it never pops up.

Sounds like your project dependencies aren't correct.  Make sure that the main form project  is dependent on the library *project* that has the `ProjectStartupActions()` function (and not dependent on some already built library assembly).

This should make it so VS will rebuild the library assembly when necessary and refer to the newly built assembly.

You might need to do a full clean/rebuild to get things sync'ed up again as well. You might also need to check and update any deployment projects/scripts that you might have.

Comment: I opened My Project>>References for the main project. Target location for the library was the library's Debug folder. Nevertheless, I removed the reference, and saved. Obviously I couldn't run because there were numerous error. I clicked Add, selected the Projects tab, and re-added the library project. Then I re-checked it as an imported namespace. The errors cleared out, so I cleaned the solution and rebuilt and ran it. The breakpoint still failed to break. I've done other little things such as moving the breakpoint, or removing it and running then re-adding.

Comment: I tried something else that didn't work. After I went through the process I described in my comment it got me thinking that there has to be a DLL for the library somewhere that the project is using. I did a search for the DLL in the solution folder and found a few in some Release folders that were artifacts from earlier Release builds. I went ahead and completely cleared out all Release folders for every project. Then I cleaned the solution again. Rebuilt it again. Then ran it again. Fail again.

Comment: When you're in the debugger look at the modules window to see where the library assembly is loading from.  That might give you a clue  either for a file that needs to be deleted or a project configuration option that needs changed.