# Upgrading VS2010 Console Application to VS2013 breaks breakpoints

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

I have a VS2010 C# Console application. In this application, I have a series of break points that work fine. I upgraded to VS2013 Premium, ran the wizard to convert my application and ran the project. The project runs and functions correctly.

However, none of my break points actually stop the debugger. The lines of code these break points are on are obviously being executed because my results are correct, or `WriteLine`s are occurring as they should after I proceed through the break points.

I've seen posts on MSDN about switching to Managed Compatibility Mode [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2e3e5970-ee52-4d56-984a-788da1e0091f/vs2013-debugger-not-working-mfcccli-w-previous-version-of-mfc-library?forum=vsdebug). The ideas in these posts didn't help.

Further, a brand new project created in VS2013 will execute the break points as expected.

Some of the similar questions here on SO relate to the upgrade from VS2008 to VS2010. I've tried some of these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728243/visual-studio-some-breakpoints-not-breaking) as well, again with no effect.

Did the wizard as me a question about break points that I missed? Or, is there another setting that I need to modify in VS2013 to properly use break points in a C# Console application that has been upgraded from a previous version?

Comment: I assume you run the debug build in the debugger. I don't know whether the following will work, but at least it should be worth a try: Export your breakpoints to an XML, delete the breakpoints from your project, rebuild the project without the breakpoint (perhaps restart VS before building, i don't know), then reimport the breakpoints from the XML again. Perhaps that gets rid of any issue with the 'old' VS2010 breakpoints...

Comment: I am sure it has something to do with different format of pdb. Did you try to disable-enable breakpoints?

Comment: @T.S. Yes. I've tried removing and readding them as well. No change

Comment: @linquize, that had no effect.